# Responsive footer issue with spoiler. Joomla (JSN Megazine PRO template)

Tags: joomla-3.x, responsive-web-design

I can't make a responsive footer in joomla.
The problem manifests itself when using the spoiler widget (Shortcode Ultimate http://bdthemes.net/demo/joomla/shortcode/en/shortcodes/spoiler.html)
When you open the spoiler, the information that is in it goes behind the footer and is not visible. It is necessary that when the spoiler is opened, the footer automatically shifts down, depending on the content of the spoiler.
Screen and link I attach:
Pic: 
[image: Spoiler Issue]
Url:
http://miku.sky-soft.com.ua/index.php/drukovani-visited
Click on the first right item with the icon of the graduation cap
Help, please with a problem!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13881548/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bottom margin or padding to your  element ( or wherever most appropriate) that is the height of your footer bar. That way there will always be room under your content and nothing will get stuck behind your footer bar ( for not just your spoiler extension but any content).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but did not quite understand where exactly? Please help )

Comment: I'd make the change in your template's main CSS file. You can modify it by going to Extensions > Templates > Templates; Select your active template; locate your main CSS file and add your modifications there. Most likely you'll want to look for a "body" style and add a padding-bottom to it, but it may depend on how your particular template is coded. If everything I just set confuses you then you'll need to fix the link to your site so I can take a look at it (the link to your site is currently broken).

Comment: Sorry for a broken link. Working link is http://miku.sky-soft.com.ua/index.php/drukovani-vydannia
Click on the first right item with the icon of the graduation cap